# Jgit- How to get list of merge commits between two dates using Jgit?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, jenkins

I need list of commits from a date extracted from last Jenkins Build and get a list of merge commits since that date. 
I've coded so far to obtain list of merge commits. Just need a solution to extract these commits between specified dates. 
Reference code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException , GitAPIException{
    ArrayList<String> CommitIds=new ArrayList<String>();
    FileRepositoryBuilder repositoryBuilder = new FileRepositoryBuilder();
    repositoryBuilder.setMustExist( true );
    repositoryBuilder.setGitDir(new File("/path/to/repo"));
    Repository repo = repositoryBuilder.build();
    Git git = Git.open( new File( "/path/to/repo" ) );
    RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo);
    git.checkout().setName("branch").call();
    String branchName=repo.getBranch();
    System.out.println(branchName);
    Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();
    RevCommit masterHead = walk.parseCommit( repo.resolve( "refs/heads/master" ));
    for (RevCommit commit : commits) {
        boolean foundInThisBranch = false;

        RevCommit otherHead = walk.parseCommit(repo.resolve(
                commit.getName()));
        for (Map.Entry<String, Ref> e : repo.getAllRefs().entrySet()) {
            if (e.getKey().startsWith(Constants.R_HEADS)) {
                if (walk.isMergedInto(otherHead, walk.parseCommit(
                        e.getValue().getObjectId()))) {
                    String foundInBranch = e.getValue().getName();
                    if (branchName.equals(foundInBranch)) {
                        foundInThisBranch = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (foundInThisBranch)
        {
            CommitIds.add(commit.getName());


     } 

      }

    System.out.println(CommitIds);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`LogCommand#setRevFilter(RevFilter)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.8.0.201706111038-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/api/LogCommand.html#setRevFilter-org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.filter.RevFilter-) with [`CommitTimeRevFilter#between(Date,Date)`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.8.0.201706111038-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/filter/CommitTimeRevFilter.html#between-java.util.Date-java.util.Date-), e. g.:

```
ObjectId masterId = git.getRepository().exactRef("refs/heads/master").getObjectId();
Date since = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-08-01");
Date until = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse("2017-08-10");
RevFilter between = CommitTimeRevFilter.between(since, until);
for (RevCommit commit : git.log().add(masterId).setRevFilter(between).call()) {
    System.out.println(  "* "
                       + commit.getId().getName()
                       + " "
                       + commit.getShortMessage());
}
```